# Place icon right next to it and in the center

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, bulma

I would like to create a three step guide and between the first and second and the second and third there should be a symbol '>'. However, the CSS does not work properly for me and the symbol is not placed correctly.

My question is how can I place the symbol in the middle of the height of the text ? Say the height is heading + text and this should then be to the right of each. (See my example)

How do I have to design the css ? I also use Bulma as a grid system.

```
<div className="columns has-text-white ml-6 mr-6">
  <div className="column mt-4 further-step">
    <div className="has-text-white">
      <div className="">
        <h3 className="has-text-white subtitle is-4">Heading 1</h3>
        <p>Text 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="column mt-4 further-step">
    <div className="has-text-white">
      <h3 className="has-text-white subtitle is-4">Heading 2</h3>
      <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="column mt-4 further-step">
    <div className="has-text-white">
      <h3 className="has-text-white subtitle is-4">Heading 3</h3>
      <p>Text 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

style.scss

```
.color-section {
  background-color: green;

  .further-step {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .further-step::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "\f054";
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -50px;
  }
}
```

I want something like:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX22l.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by setting the parent container position to relative and the :after element as absolute like you have it there but add top: 35%; it should position the arrow 35% from the height of the parent container. Play around with the top value a bit. No need for margin

try

```
.color-section {
    background-color: green;

    .further-step {
        display:inline-block; 
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 60px;
    }
    .further-step::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '\f054';
        font-size: 45px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        right: -50px;
        top: 30%; // change this value until its centered
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm using `right: 0;` and `margin-right: -50px;` is disappear and the complete website postponed

Comment: Try add padding-right: 60px to .further-step. You don't even need margin-right. You can do right: -50px; and it will do the same thing. I'll edit the answer